# Adding breaks after arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to add line breaks after writing out each array/function in the output box but cant seem to find a solution for it. I've tried adding it as a variable, comment etc. Any ideas? Thank you.
Example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,23,25 "new line"
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,23,25 "new line"
```

code

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Oppgave 1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>

        </style>
        <script>

            window.onload = oppstart;

            var output = "";
            var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,23,25];
            var sum = 0;



            function oppstart(){ 
            //Forlengs
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                skrivUt();
                }
            //Baklengs
                for(var i = arr.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                skrivUt();
                }
            //Annethver
                for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
                skrivUt();
                }
            //Mindre enn 10
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                if(arr[i] < 10)
                skrivUt();
            //Partall
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                if(arr[i]  % 2 === 0)
                skrivUt();

            function skrivUt(){
                output += arr[i] + " ";
                //sum += arr[i];
                document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = output;
                }

            }   


        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="out"></p>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Is Not Exact  Answer This Is Only Example Of Your Question Just Use "\n" For Next Line In Your Script

```js
   window.onload = oppstart;

            var output = "";
            var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,23,25];
            var sum = 0;



            function oppstart(){ 
            //Forlengs
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                skrivUt();
                  
                }
            //Baklengs
                for(var i = arr.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                skrivUt();
                }
            //Annethver
                for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {
                skrivUt();
                }
            //Mindre enn 10
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                if(arr[i] < 10)
                skrivUt();
            //Partall
                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                if(arr[i]  % 2 === 0)
                skrivUt();

            function skrivUt(){
                output += arr[i]+"\n";
                 alert(output);
                //sum += arr[i];
                document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = output;
                
                }

            }
```

```html
        <p id="out"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

use array.push instead of concatinating the values.